# How to get SERVER date using Ajax call?

Tags: javascript, php, html, ajax

Right now i am trying to get the date of local host. But the ajax request is not working successfully. How do i do it?

Html code: It has the ajax code in script tag.

```html
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
<title>Untitled Document</title>
<script language=”javascript” type=”text/javascript”>

function ajaxFunction()
{
var xh;
try
  {
  // Firefox, Opera 8.0+, Safari
  xh=new XMLHttpRequest();
  }
catch (e)
  {
    alert("Your browser does not support AJAX!");
   }

  xh.onreadystatechange=stateChanged;

  xh.open("GET","19_time.php",true);
  xh.send(null);
  tt=timer_function();
  
 
}

function stateChanged() 
  {
   if(xh.readyState==4)
    document.getElementById("time").innerHTML=xh.responseText;
}

 function timer_function(){
  var mytime= setInterval(AjaxFunction,1000);
}

window.addEventListener('load',AjaxFunction,false);
</script>
</head>

<body>
<html>
<body>

 <div id="time"  style="height:10%; width:30%; margin:4%; margin-top:10%; border:5px solid #804;  font-size:26px; " ></div>
</body>
</html>
```

Php code: To connect to  the server and send result

```html
<?Php
///////// Database Details , add  here  ////
//$dbhost_name = "localhost";
//$username = "root";                  //  Login user id 
//$password = "";                  //   Login password
/////////// End of Database Details //////


 //$con=mysql_connect($dbhost_name,$username,$password) or die("Couldn't connect: ".mysql_error());
 //mysql_select_db($database,$con) or die("Error selecting database: ".mysql_error());

//////// Do not Edit below /////////

  $con = mysql_connect('localhost', 'root', '');
  
  $msg="";
  $msg .=$con->date('Y-m-d H:i:s');
  echo $msg;
  
 


?>
```

Comment: What is the error you getting ?

Comment: To begin with there are lots of errors on your HTML page. Though `javascript` is a generally liberal language, its still case-sensitive. You've used `ajaxFunction` in the function definition, and `AjaxFunction` everywhere else.

Comment: Validate your html markup using the [online W3C Validator](http://validator.w3.org/check) before you start finding errors.

Answer (score 0):

date() is not a function in mysql_connect, so $con->date() will do nothing. date() is a php function.

If you're trying to get the mysql server time:

```
$con = mysql_connect('localhost', 'root', '');
$qry = "SELECT NOW()";
$sql_time = $con->mysql_query($qry);
echo json_encode($sql_time);
```

Else, if you just want the php server time (should be system time) simply have this code:

```
echo json_encode(date('Y-m-d H:i:s'));
```

When sending response data from php back to the client after an ajax call, make sure you json_encode the response.

Comment: I did echo using json_encode ...but at the client side i  have    document.getElementById("time").innerHTML=xh.responseText;   i.e  responseText takes the response . How do i get  the response using json_encode

Comment: You don't change anything to get the response. When you echo a json encoded response back to the javascript on the client, the response is encoded inside of a json object which javascript can then read. Because you are sending a Json string back, what you may have to do is "document.getElementById("time").innerHTML = JSON.parse(xh.responseText)". This will display the returned string without the quotes around it.

Answer (score 0):

First, try to use jQuery to simplify your JavaScript and ensure it will work on most browsers:

```
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.11.2.min.js"></script>
<script language=”javascript” type=”text/javascript”>
$( document ).ready(function() {
  $.ajax({
    url: "19_time.php",
    cache: false // Ensure each request will hit the server
  })
  .done(function( serverDate ) {
    $( "#time" ).html( serverDate ); // Update the HTML with the server response
  });
});
</script>
```

Then, if you want only the server date, you don't need to query the database:

```
<?php
  echo date('Y-m-d H:i:s')
?>
```